# Proposing a logo for Windows Phone SE

Tags: feature-request, design

This looks like a healthy Stack Exchange site and I want to try and make it better. How about a logo?

I don't really have any thoughts on some header for this site, but what I can think of is a logo design.

So here's the one I made:

[image: Windows Phone Stack Exchange]

The meaning of this logo is that it obviously is a Windows Phone, but the color scheme has given it a meaning. They're all the logos from Windows and their respective color slots.

> Red-Orange = Windows 9x
>
>  Green - Windows XP
>
>  Blue - Windows 10
>
>  Yellow - Windows Vista/7
>
>  Text - Windows 8

Should we get this Stack Exchange its logo?

> Proposed logo will be used for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358936/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2021/359100#359100).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your enthusiasm is commendable, but

> This looks like a healthy Stack Exchange site

No it doesn't. [2 questions](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions) have been asked so far. This is not surprising since [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) has been discontinued since *2017*. I'm actually surprised it hasn't been shut down yet.

Also, Stack Exchange sites only get a logo as part of their custom design, and there's quite a backlog for that, and it's unclear whether sites which ['graduated' because of their age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232) will get a custom design at all.